# Selecting multiple ListBox items in the same ListBox with one click

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

How can I programmatically select other items in a ListBox by clicking an item in the same ListBox? This is a c# winforms project.

For example when I click Clothes below, Pants and Shirts would need to highlight automatically. The same goes for Auto Parts which would highlight Tires and Transmissions.

```
Clothes
Pants
Tires
Shirts
Transmissions
Auto Parts
```

I have my ListBox bound to a DataSource (itemList) and I tried to add an "itemIndex" to each item in my list so I could handle the sorting (I'm sure there is probably a better way?) which made sense to me at the time, but I couldn't figure out how to actually make it work outside my head...

Here is my current code. Any suggestions would be fantastic.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace listBox_test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingList<Item> itemList = new BindingList<Item>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowData();
    }
    private void ShowData()
    {
        this.listBox1.DataSource = itemList;
        this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "ItemName";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddItem(itemIndex: 0, itemName: "Clothes", itemPrice: 0.95);
        AddItem(itemIndex: 1, itemName: "Pants", itemPrice: 0.95);
        AddItem(itemIndex: 2, itemName: "Tires", itemPrice: 0.95);
        AddItem(itemIndex: 3, itemName: "Shirts", itemPrice: 0.95);
        AddItem(itemIndex: 4, itemName: "Transmissions", itemPrice: 0.95);
        AddItem(itemIndex: 5, itemName: "Auto Parts", itemPrice: 0.95);
    }

    // Add an item to the list
    private void AddItem(int itemIndex, string itemName, double itemPrice)
    {
        itemList.Add(new Item(itemIndex, itemName, itemPrice));
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // SelectChild(); ??
    }
}
public class Item
{
    public int ItemIndex { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public double ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public Item(int itemIndex, string itemName, double itemPrice)
    {
        ItemIndex = itemIndex;
        ItemName = itemName;
        ItemPrice = itemPrice;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have some sort of relationship (*likely* one key to multiple values) declared between them such that your program knows which item(s) is(are) related to which item(s)

As an example, below is how it is implemented for `string` to `string[]` relationship using `Dictionary<string, string[]>`:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>(){
    {"Clothes", new string[] {"Pants","Shirts"}},
    {"Auto Parts", new string[] {"Tires","Transmissions"}}
};
```

Then, by putting your `ListBox.SelectionMode` as `MultiSimple`, and based on the `Key` (`string`), you could then select the `Value` (`string[]`) by using `ListBox.SetSelected`

To implement what you want fully, however, I found out it quite *tricky* - especially if you use `SelectedIndex` event. There are at least two other things you need to consider:

1. When you select something inside the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handelr, it will cause the program to trigger *another* `SelectedIndexChanged`. This, if not carefully handled, may cause `StackOverflow` exception due to recursion calls.
2. You might want to have some default functionality for item which are *not* in the `key` list (such as `Shirts`). To do so, you might need to record what the *last* selected item is. *But*, unfortunately, the `SelectedItems` and `SelectedIndices` of `ListBox` does not go by selection *chronological* order, but by *sequential* order. Thus, you cannot infer what is the last selected item from either `SelectedItems` or `SelectedIndices` and thus you may need to implement your own "memory" for the last (singular) selected item.

Considering few things above, the final, safe, implementation may look like this (commented):

```
//Creates relationship
Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>(){
    {"Clothes", new string[] {"Pants","Shirts"}},
    {"Auto Parts", new string[] {"Tires","Transmissions"}}
};

private bool isProcessingSelection = false; //prevents stack overflow
List<string> listBox1_lastSelections = new List<string>(); //creates memory

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {            
    if (isProcessingSelection) //to prevent stack overflow exception because of recursive call
        return;

    isProcessingSelection = true; //set true whenever processing

    List<string> currentSelections = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<string>().ToList();
    string lastSelection = listBox1_lastSelections.Count > currentSelections.Count ?
        listBox1_lastSelections.Except(currentSelections).FirstOrDefault() :
        currentSelections.Except(listBox1_lastSelections).FirstOrDefault();   
    //get the last selected item by comparison of current and last selection

    int index = listBox1.Items.IndexOf(lastSelection); //the last selected index

    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; ++i) {
        if (i == index) //do not process the last selected index
            continue;
        listBox1.SetSelected(i, false); //make everything else false
    }

    if (dict.ContainsKey(lastSelection)) { //if the last selection is among the item in the dictionary, highlight the rests
        string[] related = dict[lastSelection];
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; ++i)
            if (related.Contains(listBox1.Items[i].ToString()))
                listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
    }

    listBox1_lastSelections = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<string>().ToList(); //update the last selection

    isProcessingSelection = false; //prepare for the next, non recursive call
}
```

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thanks for that. Any input via keyboard crashes the program but I think it should be an easy fix

Answer (score 0):

you need to loop through your listbox and set selected to true

```
  for (int i = 0; i < myListBox.Items.Count;i++)
   {
       myListBox.SetSelected(i, true);
   }
```